# Hibernate setMaxResult causes exception

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I am using criteria with hibernate session (not entity manager) whenever I use setMaxResult I get exception as follows:

**Code Segment:**

```
crit2.add(criterion).setFirstResult(first);
```

It works perfect as above, but whenever I add setmax result as:

```
crit2.add(criterion).setFirstResult(first).setMaxResults(max);
```

I get exception. I tried 2 Dialects and get 2 different exceptions:

**Dialect:** org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
**When:** It never give results but always gives exception below
**Exception:** Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

**Dialect:** org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
**When:** It returns first page as expected but whenever I try to get 2nd or more page I get
**Exception:** Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.

Btw I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

**Edit:**

I realized the problem it is about turkish-english characterset difference. Hibernate use lower letter of every field but in I it generates i but for Sqlserver lowerletter of I is ı (as in turkish)

**For example:** *sonIslemTarihi* is the property name and hibernate creates query as *sonislemtarihi* and gives error and I changed query as *sonıslemtarihi* and executed from sql server management studio and it worked out as expected.

how can I handle this?

Comment: Can you change logger level & check the generated query.

Comment: @NayanWadekar I added stacktraces for your information, but I cannot give you sql query for not to reveal project's domain model (my company don't allow me to) but certainly query is damaged especially for SQLServer2008Dialect. But I can't change queries because I want to use criteria.

Comment: No actual query needed, you can mask confidential data & update similar one. Also can you post first & max values.

Comment: first value is 0 for first page and 10 for second page, and max value is 10. I am a little bit busy right now, I'll post masked sql query later. (by the way, thanks for your interest @NayanWadekar)

Comment: I realized the problem it is about turkish-english characterset difference. Hibernate use lower letter of every field but in I it generates i but for Sqlserver lowerletter of I is ı (as in turkish)

**For example:** _sonIslemTarihi_ is the property name and hibernate creates query as _sonislemtarihi_ and gives error and I changed query as _sonıslemtarihi_ and executed from sql server management studio and it worked out as expected.

 how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

*[Adding answer as it was getting too long, inappropriate for comment]*

I am not much familiar with MS-SQL, but `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect` seems correct dialect.

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</property>
```

There is some mismatch between database character encoding & the one generated by hibernate. Try changing these configuration parameters & observe the query generated.

Comment: it didn't work, still same result. The problem is whenever I add setMaxResult(max) hibernate changed all characters of query to lowercase but unless it, hibernate use normal formatting. Is there any way to prevent Hibernate to change all characters to lowercase?

Comment: @bdogru If your database is in Turkish locale, then need to configure same in fibernate configuration too, possibly - [tr_TR]. Also can refer this link - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/i#browse/HHH-8765 its fixed I think, look at your hibernate version.